# How to read xml tag, if there is another tag used in php?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I am trying to read xml tag, But there is one issue, If another tag is there inside a tag I am getting only it's attribute.

Example:
I am have a xml file

```
    $myXMLData =
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<note>
<to><hello role='admin'/>Hello World</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>";
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

Output:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [to] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [hello] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [role] => admin
                        )

                )

        )

    [from] => Jani
    [heading] => Reminder
    [body] => Don't forget me this weekend!
)
```

But I want title "Hello World". Can anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the value of a SimpleXML element as an object, you have to cast it to a string (or int, or ...) instead:

```
$myXMLData = "<title><anchor id='page1' role='first'/>Xyz Title</title>";
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo "<pre>";
echo (string)$xml;
```

Output:

```
Xyz Title
```

For your revised question, just

```
echo (string)$xml->to;
```

Output:

```
Hello world
```

Comment: You don't need `(string)`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you are correct for an `echo`. In many other use cases you do, so I prefer to use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks, But I have this type of xml data <chapter label="Chapter 1" id="ch1">
<title><anchor id="page1" role="first"/>Cardiothoracic and vascular system</title><toc role="none"></toc></chapter>

Comment: thanks @Nick , I have updated my question, Any idea how can I have get this?